# Disable Keyevents for Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form in a Bootstrap Carousel. If the cursor is in an input field I cannot use the left and right button to move the cursor because they trigger the carousel to slide.

My question is how to disable the carousel movements when pressing any keys.

Comment: WoW it seems like I am not the only person experiencing this issue. Looks like it's a Carousel bug :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up bootstrap.js, you will find this little snippet of code:

```
Carousel.prototype.keydown=function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 37:
            this.prev();
            break;

        case 39:
            this.next();
            break;

        default:
            return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
};
```

Commenting or removing it will solve your problem. But I dont want to change the library so I will have to wait for bootstrap team to fix it.

PS: try adding `data-keyboard="false"` into your `class="carousel slide"` element and see if it helps? Needs bootstrap 3.3.0 though

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-keyboard="false"></div>
```

This method solves problem.

Comment: that's not a method, I guess you want to show that there is a property keyboard that can be set with the help of user attributes. Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
$("#selector").off('keydown.bs.carousel');
```